# Error running a react-native Android app - BatchedBridge

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I am trying to bring-up our react-native app on Android. It is working fine on iOS. When I try to run the debug build, react-native throws the below error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object
(evaluating 'require('BatchedBridge').flushedQueue')
("line":1 in generated bundle)
```

How do I figure out what is causing the error? 
Any advice is greatly appreciated. Saw online that sometimes such an error message can contain the column, but in my case there is only the line number. I am running react-native 0.17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a messed-up path, in one place. Fixing that alleviated the problem.

It seems that react-native Android is ready for business, as much as anything...
It would be nice to have better diagnostics, and perhaps integrate react-native Android with an IDE to the point where the IDE [plugin] would be able to make inclusion of Android modules into config more seamless. Xcode linking configuration is also not perfect, but it is slightly easier on developers.

Since react-native is a young project, there is no reason to not expect such tools in the future, I hope.